# Extracting a number from a 3d array that is the only one in the row or in the column c / c++

Tags: c, arrays, math, sudoku

What i'm trying to do is a non-recorsive sudoku solver, I have an array sudoku[9][9] that is the sudoku itself with 0 as empty spaces and an array of arrays solutions[9][9][9] where all the possible solution are initially filled (from 1 to 9) and they became 0's if they don't respect one of the rules. 
I'll explain with an example, ignoring for a second the 3*3 square rule for easiness:
if the first 3 rows of the sudoku matrix are

```
0 9 0 3 4 6 8 7 5
7 8 0 5 0 2 6 3 0
6 2 3 9 5 1 7 8 4
```

in the first 27 rows of the solution matrix we'll have

```
0.0 120000000    1.0 123456789   2.0 123456789
0.1 123456789    1.1 123456789   2.1 123456789
0.2 120000000    1.2 100400009   2.2 123456789
0.3 123456789    1.3 123456789   2.3 123456789
0.4 123456789    1.4 100000009   2.4 123456789
0.5 123456789    1.5 123456789   2.5 123456789
0.6 123456789    1.6 123456789   2.6 123456789
0.7 123456789    1.7 123456789   2.7 123456789
0.8 123456789    1.8 100000009   2.8 123456789
```

I need a function that checks if there is no solution equal to mine in the solutions of the other free cells (row, column, 3*3 square). If so return that solution (mine is correct). for example in this case it have to return "4" for the cell 1.2, since in the other free cells (1.4 and 1.8), "4" is not a solution. I'm having a very  hard time doing the loop chain, here is my code only for the check in the solutions of the row (still, for easiness), the printf is only for debugging purpose:

```
    int verifyequalsolutions (int sudoku[9][9], int solutions[9][9][9], int i, int j)
{
    int k=0, a=0, z=0;
    int rowsolution=0;

    for (k=1; k<9; k++)             //scanning solutions[i][j][k], i'm cycling k to compare every existing pre-existing solution for my element
    {
        for (a=0; a<9; a++)         //
        {
            if (a!=j && sudoku[i][a]==0)
            {
            for (z=1;z<9;z++)       //scanning solutions[i][a][z]
                    {
                          if (solutions[i][j][k]==solutions[i][a][z])
                        {   rowsolution=0;
                            a=10;
                            z=10;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (z<=9) {rowsolution=solutions[i][j][k];}
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    if (rowsolution!=0)
    {
        printf("for [%d][%d] i found something in the row!: %d\n",i,j, rowsolution);
        return rowsolution;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since the output is actually wrong I want to analize my doubts one by one:
is my loop exit legit? can i just increase the for variable over the condition to exit?

I hope that someone finds this challange interesting and is so kind to help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't be the only one that is struggling to find the *question* in this question.

Comment: okay, the problem is that the output is wrong but i don't know were i'm wrong!

Comment: Try freelancers' site.

Comment: I want to specify that is not a work, just a school project and one of the reasons that the code is posted here is to make it readable to my colleagues and teacher.

Comment: Does the question assume that `int solutions[9][9][9]` will hold all possible solutions? That array can hold only 9 solutions. There are apparently 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960 possible Soduko solutions. The array size you need will depend on the number of pre-filled cells there are.

Comment: int solutions[9][9][9] is formatted as you see on the top, each solutions[9][9][ ] contains 9 numbers from 1 to 9 at the beginning, but they are replaced by 0's when the program runs until only 1 solution is different from 0. I don't understand when you say "6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960 possible Soduko solutions", are they the quantity of solutions?

Comment: @Francesco Porcelli, I mean it's hard for brain and probably cost 5-15$